# How to calculate the arc length of y = C/x

Tags: calculus, integration

## What I'm trying to do:

Calculate the arc length of the function y = C/x for a given range of x.
For testing purposes, C = 10, x = 2 to x = 8 (but any numbers will do to be honest).

Feel free to skip the rest if it's a ridiculously simple thing a monkey could do and you just want to do a quick reply :)  I am interested in the general form, and more importantly how to work it out, but I am grateful for *any* assistance you can offer.

## What the computer says:

Before I explain how I've failed miserably so far, I came across a link to the Wolfram integrator this morning.  I plugged the formula below in and it gave a [grotesque integral](http://integrals.wolfram.com/index.jsp?expr=sqrt%281%2B100%2Fx%5E4%29&random=false).  I'm hoping that is just a case of a computer brute forcing the matter rather than using some art.  Surely the answer can't be *that* terrible...  Can it?

## What I've done so far:

Feel free to skip this bit unless you have the time, or want to despair at the education of the masses...  Just wanted to show I have tried (and failed, repeatedly).

According to the interwebs I can integrate

$$
\int\sqrt{(1+(\frac{dy}{dx})^2)} dx
$$

to calculate the arc length of a function.  Turns out I can't actually :)  My calculus is *bad* so I've done some Googling followed by various attempts.   In reverse order -

**Attempt #3**

Factoring/simplifying 1+(dy/dx)^2 so hopefully I can take the sqrt of a square and make this a lot simpler.  Plugging in my numbers

$$
1 + (\frac{dy}{dx})^2 = 1 + (\frac{-10}{x^2}) = 1 + 100x^{-4}
$$

Looks like it might be factorable as a square at first glance.  Alas I can't see an obvious (ax^-2 - b)^2 form.  The best I can see is

$$
-1 (10x^{-2} - 1) (10x^{-2} + 1)
$$

giving us the sqrt term

$$
\sqrt{-1 (10x^{-2} - 1) (10x^{-2} + 1)}
$$

Kinda stuck beyond sqrt[-1] = i, and to be fair I'm thinking imaginary numbers aren't going to make this thing easier.

$$
\int i \sqrt{10x^{-2} - 1} \sqrt{10x^{-2} + 1} dx
$$

I can't find how to integrate the two sqrt forms though.  Are there known methods, or is this a dead end?

**Attempt #2**

I came across u-substitution, along with the integration of

$$
\sqrt{1 + x^2} = \frac{x \sqrt{x^2 + 1)} + asinh(x)}{2}
$$

That looked promising - I thought I might be able to calculate dy/dx for my two values of x, throw them in that formula and voila.  I was wrong.  I think it's to do with the dx term which I am missing.

**Attempt #1**

Straight up u-sub on the acr length formula at the top.  It ain't pretty (or short)...

For my numbers above dy/dx = -10x^-2

Plugging that into the integration above I get

$$
\int\sqrt{1 + (-10x^{-2})^2} dx =
\int\sqrt{1 + 100x^{-4}} dx
$$

I've read apparantly contradictory things about u-sub.  One article says you can only use it where the integral is in a particular form (f(g(x)) g'(x)), but another one seems to "force" it into a usable form by differentiating u and multiplying dx by 1/du.  I may well have misunderstood that...

$$
u = 1 + 100x^{-4}
$$
$$
\frac{du}{dx} = -400x^{-5}
$$
$$
\int\sqrt{u} \frac{x^5}{-400} du
$$

Now that has both x and u in it, which I assume is broken.  I've read that I can rearrange the u formula to get x in terms of u and substitute that for the x term(s).

$$
u = 1+100x^{-4}
$$
$$
u-1 = 100x^{-4}
$$
$$
x^4 = \frac{100}{(u-1)}
$$
$$
x = (\frac{100}{(u-1)})^{0.25}
$$

Substituting that back into the formula above I get

$$
\int\sqrt{u} \frac{(\frac{100}{(u-1)})^{0.25})^5}{-400} du
$$
$$
\int\sqrt{u} \frac{(\frac{100}{(u-1)})^{1.25}}{-400} du
$$

It looks better, but it's still not in a form I can integrate as far as I can tell.  I guess I can treat the -1/400 as a constant and pull that out to the left of the integral?  That still leaves us with

$$
\frac{1}{-400} \int\sqrt{u} (\frac{100}{(u-1)})^{1.25} du
$$

Thinking out loud, can I split that into two parts maybe?
No you can't - thanks tired for pointing out the error

Gah, my brain is imploding at this point.  I assumed that as the arc length formula was merely given "as is" it should be relatively straightforward to integrate, but I'm really struggling.  My calculus needs much work...

Comment: attempt 1 is wrong for sure. you can't split an integral like this!

Comment: again in step 3: this kind of splitting is forbidden $\int f g \neq  \int f \int g  $
Please recall the basic integration rules!

Comment: btw: To solve this integral correctly is indeed quite difficult. The solution includes Ellipitc functions.